# Findbugs - Sequence of calls to java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap may not be atomic

Tags: java, concurrency, synchronization, findbugs

I have following code in my project

```
// Declaration

private ConcurrentHashMap<Long, ConcurrentHashMap<String, Object>> instanceSpecificBeanMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
```

Use of map

```
ConcurrentHashMap<String, Object> beanMapForInstance = instanceSpecificBeanMap.get(currentInstanceId);
    Object beanObject = null;
    if(beanMapForInstance == null){
        synchronized (initLockObject) {
            beanMapForInstance = instanceSpecificBeanMap.get(currentInstanceId);
            if(beanMapForInstance == null){
                beanMapForInstance = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
                instanceSpecificBeanMap.put(currentInstanceId, beanMapForInstance);
            }
        }
    }
```

I think above operation is atomic, although findbugs is showing it as issue? am I missing something here?

**EDIT**

`beanMapForInstance` is accessed from this class only. No other class has access to this variable.

Also,
Currently we are using **Java 7**

Comment: A thread could retrieve an empty map when calling `ISBM.get(id);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `putIfAbsent` method. It is precisely intended to atomically put a new value in the map if none exist for the given key.

```
ConcurrentHashMap<String, Object> newMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
ConcurrentHashMap<String, Object> beanMapForInstance = instanceSpecificBeanMap.putIfAbsent(currentInstanceId, newMap);
if (beanMapForInstance == null) {
    beanMapForInstance = newMap;
}
(... work with beanMapForInstance ...)
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Although I could not get why findbugs is showing that current code is not atomic. Can you please add some explanation?

Comment: Your first test of `beanMapForInstance` makes an unprotected read (not synchronized, not volatile) so a thread could cache its value (`null`) in a register and never see that a new instance has been created. Thus, you might end up creating multiple maps for a particular bean.

Comment: But if in first test any threads finds that beanMapForInstance is null then it will try to instantiate it by entering into synchronized block. Now there is again a check which will fail if any other thread has already initialized beanMapForInstance. Also I forgot to mention that beanMapForInstance is used internally, I will update the question.

Answer (score 2):

You can simplify this and solve the problem using [`computeIfAbsent`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html#computeIfAbsent-K-java.util.function.Function-) from Java 8:

```
ConcurrentHashMap<String, Object> beanMapForInstance = 
        instanceSpecificBeanMap.computeIfAbsent(
            currentInstanceId, 
            k -> new ConcurrentHashMap<>()  // might need explicit generics
        );
```